# How to access TFrame's canvas?

Tags: delphi, tframe

Using: Delphi XE2, VCL 32-bit application, Windows 8

I'm trying to paint the background of my frame onto a panel (I'm using TJvPanel, because it exposes the OnPaint event) which is a child control of the frame.

After reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15294099/using-tframe-how-do-i-properly-access-the-tcanvas-property-just-as-in-a-tform) and adding a canvas as a field, I am still not successful.

After calling ShowAddReceiptPanel, it should draw the frame's (TfrmMyFrame) window contents with all the controls already on it (which include a grid and a pagecontrol) on the foreground panel, grayscaled, after being processed by the ProEffectImage method, but instead it shows an opaque white background. Am I missing something?

Here's my code:

```
type
  TfrmMyFrame = class(TFrame)
    pnlHdr: TPanel;
    pnlAddNewBG: TJvPanel;
    procedure pnlAddNewBGPaint(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FBGImg: TProEffectImage;
    Fcnvs: TCanvas;

    procedure PaintWindow(DC: HDC); override;
    procedure ShowAddReceiptPanel;
    procedure HideAddReceiptPanel;
    procedure ResizePanel_pnlAddNewBG;

  public
    { Public declarations }
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

constructor TfrmMyFrame.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;

  FBGImg := TProEffectImage.Create(nil);
  Fcnvs := TCanvas.Create;

end;

destructor TfrmMyFrame.Destroy;
begin
  if Assigned(FBGImg) then
    FBGImg.Free;

  if Assigned(Fcnvs) then
    Fcnvs.Free;

  inherited;
end;

procedure TfrmMyFrame.ShowAddReceiptPanel;
begin
  ResizePanel_pnlAddNewBG;
  pnlAddNewBG.Visible := True;
end;

procedure TfrmMyFrame.PaintWindow(DC: HDC);
begin
  inherited;

  Fcnvs.Handle := DC;
end;

procedure TfrmMyFrame.pnlAddNewBGPaint(Sender: TObject);
var
  l, t, w, h: Integer;
  srct, drct: TRect;
begin

  // Copy Frame canvas to BGImg bitmap
  l := 0;
  t := pnlHdr.Height;
  w := ClientWidth;
  h := ClientHeight - t;

  srct := TRect.Create(l, t, w, h);
  FBGImg.Width := w;
  FBGImg.Height := h;
  drct := TRect.Create(l, t, w, h);
  FBGImg.Canvas.CopyMode := cmSrcCopy;
  FBGImg.Canvas.CopyRect(drct, Fcnvs, srct);
//  FBGImg.Picture.SaveToFile('c:\tmp\a.bmp');

  FBGImg.Effect_AntiAlias;
  FBGImg.Effect_GrayScale;

  // Draw BGImg onto Option panel
  TJvPanel(Sender).Canvas.CopyMode := cmSrcCopy;
  TJvPanel(Sender).Canvas.Draw(0, 0, FBGImg.Picture.Graphic);
end;

procedure TfrmMyFrame.ResizePanel_pnlAddNewBG;
var
  x1, y1, x2, y2: Integer;
  bmp: TBitmap;
begin
  x1 := 0;
  y1 := pnlHdr.Height;
  x2 := ClientWidth;
  y2 := ClientHeight - y1;

  pnlAddNewBG.SetBounds(x1, y1, x2, y2);
end;
```

Comment: The if Assigned tests in your destructor can and should be removed. Just call Free which includes and Assigned check.

Comment: Thanks! Free includes an Assigned check - when did they introduce that feature?

Comment: Er, in Delphi 1. I refer you to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548843/why-should-i-not-use-if-assigned-before-using-or-freeing-things/8550628#8550628

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65050463/why-canvas-is-hidden-in-all-vcl-controls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DC that you assign to your canvas handle is only valid during the PaintWindow call. You use it outside that function when it is not valid and hence the behaviour that you observe.

I think that you should be able to solve your problem by calling the [PaintTo](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.PaintTo) method. Create a bitmap of the right size and pass its canvas to PaintTo.

Comment: Do you only want to paint the background? Or the frame's children too.

Comment: Need to paint the frame's children. The front panel will show a black and white image of what lies beneath it - that is the whole purpose.

Comment: My second paragraph should cover it.

Comment: Please can you give an example of the code, as I am totally new to sending messages. Also where do I put that call in the context of my existing code?

Comment: Is there a variation of PaintTo that paints only a rectangle (TRect) instead of the whole canvas? I need to omit a rectangular region at the top of the frame (that contains a header panel).

Comment: Nevermind, I can adjust the drawing location by offsetting the Y by the needed amount:
 
TJvPanel(Sender).Canvas.Draw(0, - pnlHdr.Height, FBGImg.Picture.Graphic);

Comment: I do not think so. You need to get the whole image and then strip off the unwanted portion into a second image.

Comment: Actually your solution is far better!

Answer (score 1):

A `TFrame` does not have a canvas. You could create/add one, as `TCustomControl` does, but you do not have to. A canvas is just a handy wrapper around a Windows device context. The `PaintWindow` routine is called whenever the frame has to be (partially) redrawn. The parameter exhibits the DC, or you could obtain one with `GetDC`.

Then pseudo-code would be as follows:

```
procedure TfrmMyFrame.PaintWindow(DC: HDC);
begin
  - Resize BG image and hide it (otherwise image itself will be copied too)
  - Paint the frame's contents to the image with:
    Self.PaintTo(FBGImg.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0)
  - Process the special effects on FBGImg
  - Paint the image onto DC with:
    BitBlt(DC, 0, 0, ClientWidth, ClientHeight, FBGImage.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
end;
```

Comment: GetWindowDC does not always return the same DC.

Comment: Oops, `GetWindowDC` returns the non-client part indeed.

Comment: More than that the DC could be user supplied. As in "paint on my bitmap".

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to get access to a `Canvas` on a `TFrame` is to add a `TPaintBox` on top of it with `Align := alClient` and using its `Canvas` property.

I expect this method to work with any version of Delphi, also in the future, and therefore use it instead of the `PaintWindow` method, which seems to be tricky.

Comment: That does not, however, *get access to a Canvas on a TFrame* - it gets access to *a TPaintBox on the TFrame*, which is not the same thing at all.

Comment: `TPaintBox.Canvas` is a Canvas, in my opinion just as much as a `Canvas` created in `PaintWindow`. I first used the `PaintWindow` method, but ran into problems with fonts automatically changing. Therefore I switched to using the `TPaintBox`, which is simple and does not do anything with the Windows API around Delphi code.